# HDF5 call 'file = H5Fopen(nuceos_table_name, H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT)' returned error code -1

Tags: hdf5, slurm

when I run an executable on Linux I met an error I'm not able to explain. The executable is meant to read an .h5 file whose name is given by the nuceos_table_name variable. I already checked the filename and should be right i.e. nuceos_table_name = "./BLH_new.h5", the file is in the same folder where I launch the command from ("srun <path-to-executable>"). The error is the following

```
  HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.12.0) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 793 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibility
    minor: Unable to open file
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.12.0) thread 0:
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.12.0) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 793 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibility
    minor: Unable to open file
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.12.0) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 793 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibility
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: H5VLcallback.c line 3500 in H5VL_file_open(): open failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
minor: Can't open object
```

Thank you for helping and sorry if I haven't been clear enough, I'm new to this computer science stuff, anyway I'm here to explain better.

P.S. The code fragment which opens the file is the following:

```
   void nuc_eos_C_ReadTable(const cGH* cctkGH)
{
  DECLARE_CCTK_PARAMETERS;

  using namespace nuc_eos;
  using namespace nuc_eos_private;

  CCTK_VInfo(CCTK_THORNSTRING,"*******************************");
  CCTK_VInfo(CCTK_THORNSTRING,"Reading nuc_eos table file:");
  CCTK_VInfo(CCTK_THORNSTRING,"%s",nuceos_table_name);
  CCTK_VInfo(CCTK_THORNSTRING,"*******************************");

  CCTK_INT my_reader_process = reader_process;
  if (my_reader_process < 0 || my_reader_process >= CCTK_nProcs(cctkGH))
  {
    CCTK_VWarn(CCTK_WARN_COMPLAIN, __LINE__, __FILE__, CCTK_THORNSTRING,
               "Requested IO process %d out of range. Reverting to process 0.", my_reader_process);
    my_reader_process = 0;
  }
  const int doIO = !read_table_on_single_process || CCTK_MyProc(cctkGH) == my_reader_process;

  hid_t file;
  if (doIO && !file_is_readable(nuceos_table_name)) {
    CCTK_VError(__LINE__, __FILE__, CCTK_THORNSTRING,
               "Could not read nuceos_table_name %s \n",
               nuceos_table_name);
  }
  HDF5_DO_IO(file = H5Fopen(nuceos_table_name, H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT));

// Use these two defines to easily read in a lot of variables in the same way
// The first reads in one variable of a given type completely
```

Comment: Which mode are you using to open the file? Read-only or Write (or Append)? If you are opening in Write (or Append) mode, the file needs Read/Write permission at the OS level. That's what I'd check based on this message: `major: File accessibility`

Comment: Where could I see the mode? I'm running the executable on an online computer cluster. How could I modify the mode possibly? Thank you.

Comment: I checked on internet and this is the mode "-rw-r--r--", I should belong to the "other" category I guess thus I'm in the write only mode.

Comment: The first character (`-`) is a special permission flag we can ignore. The next 3 flags apply to the file owner and show allow and write permission. All others only have read permission. You only have a permission problem if you are not the owner. It would help if you add the code segment that opens the file to your post.

Comment: Ok, I did that.

Comment: Based on your code, it I don't think it's a permission problem. `H5Fopen` file access mode is: `H5F_ACC_RDONLY` = _An existing file is opened with read-only access. If the file does not exist, H5Fopen fails._ Check your file name/ path `nuceos_table_name` is valid